# Converting **int to an int

Tags: c++

I am trying to work with a C library, and I had to create the following bit of code:

```
void *foo = malloc(sizeof(MAGtype_MagneticModel *));
MAGtype_MagneticModel* *MagneticModels = (MAGtype_MagneticModel **)foo;
```

this is then passed to one of the C library functions as follows:

```
if(!MAG_robustReadMagModels(filename, (MAGtype_MagneticModel* (*)[]) &MagneticModels, epochs)) {
    //ERROR
}
```

When it passes the above function, I then am wanting to get the value from one of the components of this function.

```
int var = 0;
if (var < (&MagneticModels[0]->nMax)) var = (&MagneticModels[0]->nMax);
```

This gives the compiler error:

```
C2446: '<' : no conversion from 'int *' to 'int'
```

How would I go about getting the value of MagneticModels[0]->nMax instead of just pointers?

Edit: Here is the struct for MAGtype_MagneticModel:

```
typedef struct {
    double EditionDate;
    double epoch; /*Base time of Geomagnetic model epoch (yrs)*/
    char ModelName[32];
    double *Main_Field_Coeff_G; /* C - Gauss coefficients of main geomagnetic model (nT) Index is (n * (n + 1) / 2 + m) */
    double *Main_Field_Coeff_H; /* C - Gauss coefficients of main geomagnetic model (nT) */
    double *Secular_Var_Coeff_G; /* CD - Gauss coefficients of secular geomagnetic model (nT/yr) */
    double *Secular_Var_Coeff_H; /* CD - Gauss coefficients of secular geomagnetic model (nT/yr) */
    int nMax; /* Maximum degree of spherical harmonic model */
    int nMaxSecVar; /* Maximum degree of spherical harmonic secular model */
    int SecularVariationUsed; /* Whether or not the magnetic secular variation vector will be needed by program*/
    double CoefficientFileEndDate; 

} MAGtype_MagneticModel;
```

And for reference, I am working with the library found under WMM2015_Windows.zip that is [found here](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/soft.shtml)

Comment: ... and **pick a language**.

Comment: The language that I am working in is C++.  The problem comes with trying to work with the C library that I am attempting to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that may help is to to create an int variable for what you want.

This will allow you to check the variable at compile time

example

int myInt = MagneticModels[0]->nMax

should work

Here is where you need more information on the structure of

MAGtype_MagneticModel

For example, is nMax defined as an integer, or an int *

if the latter, you may need the correct address

&(MagneticModels[0]->nMax)

However, in general, using the array notation [0] 'dereferences the pointer'

Hope this helps

Comment: Added in the struct for MAGtype_MagneticModel, as well as a link to the library (if you wanted to look at that).  Note that if I try to run `int myInt = MagneticModels[0]->nMax`, the code compiles, but crashes as soon as it gets to that line of code.

Comment: try int myInt = MagneticModels[0].nMax

Comment: This gives the error: `error: C2228: left of '.nMax' must have class/struct/union type is 'MAGtype_MagneticModel *' did you intend to use '->' instead?`

Comment: Some more debugging later and I get `int myInt = MagneticModels[0]->nMax` crashes with the following exception output `Unhandled exception at 0x000000013F8694EA in GeographicLibTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000050.`

Comment: OK try 

\n

int myInt (&MagneticModels).nMax

or also try

int *myIntPtr =MagneticModels[0]->nMax

int myInt = &myIntPtr

then use myInt to see what happens

Comment: Further debugging has lead me to believe that `int myInt = MagneticModels[0]->nMax` is the correct call, and is the function that would give me the value of nMax.  However, something else is going on in the constructor calls that is causing MagneticModels to not initialize properly, and therefore when it tries to access the memory, there is nothing there and the program crashes.  It seems that I'm going to have to go back and check that implementation to solve my issue.

Comment: MagneticModels = new * MagType_model ();                 for (i=0;,i<size;i++)MagneticModels[i] = new MagType_Model; will be the initialization you'll need to use

Answer (score 0):

just dont take the address of it

```
if (var < MagneticModels[0]->nMax)....
```

Comment: This results in the program compiling, and then crashing as soon as it gets to this portion of the code.